# Is there an Equivalent to the tool "To Sphere" but to Cube?

Tags: modeling

I have a vertex based circle, and I want it to be a square. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't a tool that works the same as 'To Sphere', but there is a *Cast modifier* which can do the same job, as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could try the [*Cast Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Cast) here changing the shape of an UV-sphere:

[image]

or a circle to a quad:

[image]